# Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate with CAs doesn't work

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have a .pem certificate with chain, signed by the external CA, generated from .csr created in KeyVault.
I'm using
`Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "keyVaultName" -Name "Certificate" -FilePath "Certificate1.pem"` to import my certificate, I can see it in my KeyVault. Unfortunately the certificate is imported without CAs.
If I'll do exactly the same operation but instead of using `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` I will manually upload a certificate to KV using option `Merge Signed Request` this certificate contains desired CAs. Is there any way to do it using `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` or `az keyvault certificate import` to preserve CAs certificates?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
az keyvault certificate pending merge  --vault-name "keyVaultName" -n "Certificate" -f "Certificate1.pem"
```